# REST new and list resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have `/items/` resource, contains list of items, and I have `/items/new` resource with form for creating one item. If I need a list of items and form on one url (form and list together on one web page), and don't need them separately, what url I should choose for this coupled resources? `/items/new` or `/items/` or I should create new resource, for example `/new_and_items_resource/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Nitin, you should choose `/items`. The reasons I see are two:

1. You **don't need** a new resource to achieve what you want. So creating one would not be required. Later on you might even want to let your users delete or edit items from that page - would you create another resource called, for example, `/new_and_delete_and_edit_and_items_resource`? Not needed.
2. It doesn't make sense for a user to go to `http://www.app.com/items/new` and see a list of items.

Answer (score 1):

Choose `/items` And after create redirect to index page. Would be a good idea. You don't need any extra routing changes here.

You can do this on new as well. But url not look good in new case if you show all the items there as well.